# Indian citizen visiting Germany from US

Tags: usa, schengen, germany, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen who was studying in the United States for the past 2 years. My course is completing in December 2015 and I plan to visit Germany on my way back to India, I am moving back to India permanently.
My F-1 Visa is valid till 2018 but my I-20 will expire on 31st December 2015.
Can I apply for a Schengen Visa from the US with an expired I-20 but a valid F-1 Visa?

Answer (score 3):

Your residency status in the US is only of relevance for determining whether you can apply for a Schengen tourist visa from a consulate in the US. That you will have a change of status afterwards does not matter (at least if you tell this at the time of applying for the visa).

You can find out the rules of the respective consulate from their website. For example, in [New York](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Tourist__Visa.html), you will be fine.

Comment: To restate and underscore the point of your first sentence: US residency is not a requirement for getting a Schengen visa; it's a requirement for being able to apply for the visa *at a consulate in the US.*  I would like to underscore this point because the consular web sites are confusing.  Many people think that the residency is a requirement for the visa itself.

Comment: Thank You for the help. I know US residency is not of importance, but my question was since I am on an F-1(student) Visa, my I-20 endorsement form is also a required document in the application process and my I-20 form expires on 31st December 2015. So will I be able to apply for a Schengen Visa with an expired I-20 but a valid F-1 Visa?

Comment: Hi Aman. I don't quite get it. If your course ends in December, and you want to visit German when returning to India, you should be applying for your visa in 2015. At that point, your I-20 will still be valid, so this should not be a problem. Am I missing something here?